# Mixing Razor and Javascript: Assigning a number from Model to a Javascript variable in a view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having difficulties to assign just a basic number from Model to a Javascript variable via Razor. All that I came up with was the code below, which works, but is rather ugly as I have to convert the string value into a number. Is there any other way to just get it right away in the numeric format without any conversions?

```
var MyNumber = parseInt('@Model.MyNumber');
```

Comment: If you want to work around this bug, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22416874/895646

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set javascript variables using MVC4 with Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866539/how-to-set-javascript-variables-using-mvc4-with-razor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
var MyNumber = @Model.MyNumber;
```

or better, use the brackets to make the Razor part explicit (so it's clear that the semicolon is a Javascript semicolon):

```
var MyNumber = @(Model.MyNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked nicely. I actually tried your suggestions before but I didn't test the output as my Visual Studio 2012 is giving a syntax error (warning) in both cases (maybe a bug?). I guess I have to stop paying attention to what Visual Studio is saying and just code.

Comment: @user405723 VS2012 is reporting a syntax error for me on this exact thing too - looks like a common issue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12559317/300685

Comment: It's a bug in VS2012 and VS2013. I sent a bug report to Microsoft and they answered that "it's a very complicated issue to solve". I don't know about you guys but recently I've begun to think that the quality control of Visual Studios has slipped away.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist in eliminating the Visual Studio error, wrapping the Razor template part in an identity function call works, at a lower cost than the parse:

```
var noop = function(x) { return x; }
var MyNumber = noop(@Model.MyNumber);
```